# Implementing Two-finger scroll with Windows 7 Surface Toolkit - need some thoughts!

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multi-touch, pixelsense, gestures

I'm working with the Surface Toolkit and am willing to code a basic two-finger scroll algorithm for Scatterviews which contain FlowDocumentScrollViewer , but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

How is the math done if you take into consideration that even rotated ScatterViews should be scrollable? What else do I need to take into consideration?

One thing that bothers me is that TouchMove is fired one finger at a time so you can't really check if both fingers are down.

Its not my aim to make a perfect implementation (yet) but it should be at least useable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by surrounding the FlowDocumentScrollviewer with a SurfaceScrollViewer.
This isn't ideal since the default-behavior means you can scroll in the middle and do everything else on the outside.

Josh Santangelo modified the behaviour so it can do both ([look here](http://blog.endquote.com/post/802771198/surfacescrollviewer-behaviors)) but it only works with Surface SDK SP1 now (the one for the Surface Device) but not Surface SDK for Windows Touch Beta (the Windows 7 one).